# Append line to many files

Tags: sed, find, xargs

I want to add some text to over 200,000 files
I am trying this

```
find . -name *.txt -print | xargs -I % echo "hello world" >> %
```

But nothing is happening. When i run `find . -name *.txt` it work by itself as does `echo "hello world" >> myfile.txt`

Comment: The shell does the `>> %` part, not xargs.  Did it create a file called `%`?

Comment: Yes I now have a % and {} file =). Mikel solution works

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The shell is expanding the `>> %` part before `xargs` sees it.

If you need to do shell redirections, you'll have to try something like this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c '
    echo "hello world" >> "$0"
    ' {} \;
```

How it works:

1. `find` replaces `{}` with each file that it matches
2. `bash -c "some command" arg0...` sets `$0...` inside the `"some command"` script

Alternatively, you could use a command such as `sed` that doesn't rely on `>>` e.g.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i -e '$a\
hello world' {} \;
```

References:

- [Invoking Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash)
- [Find - Run Commands - Single File](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Single-File.html#Single-File)
- [Sed - Less Frequently-Used Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html)

Comment: I wouldn't use so many newlines, but yes.

Comment: That sed command will append 'hello world' after each line. You need `sed -i '$ahello world'` to put it only at the end of the file (my testing with GNU sed did not need the backslash-newline)

Comment: Gah!  Thanks!  I meant that, but forgot the `$`. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The original command you tried ....

```
find . -name *.txt -print | xargs -I % echo "hello world" >> %
```

needs to be changed to

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo 'hello world' >> '{}' "
```

Comment: or you can use .....   find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -i sh -c "echo 'hello world' >> '{}' "

Comment: The above commands will add "hello world" to the end of each file found by the find command.

Comment: Best solution because it uses xargs.

Answer (score -1):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
find . -name *.txt -print | parallel 'echo "hello world" >> {}'
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to [learn more](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1).